# How do I choose the first element of a list and apply to the whole set of data?

Tags: python, list, lambda

I tried to choose the clean this column named "genres" in the dataset by 1)showing the category of the genres only and removing all the words, 2)picking the first element from the list.

I'm able to do the first part (even with an error message the code still runs fine) but I failed to pick the first element and apply on the whole dataset.

Appreciate your help.

Original: [{'id': 16, 'name': 'Animation'}, {'id': 35, '...

```
movie['genres'] = movie['genres'].fillna('[]').apply(literal_eval).apply(lambda x: [i['name'] for i in x][0] if isinstance(x, list) else [])
```

After this: [Animation, Comedy, Family]

hoping to get: Animation
And apply this for the whole dataset

Please see screenshot for my code. [image: screenshot]

Comment: It is a bit hard for me to understand your question.
Can you give a short small example of an input and an output? Your input example is only partial.

Comment: @Mickey Thanks! I have updated the question with a screenshot of my problem.

Comment: @SoniaLo It would be nice if you can provide text data: to answer most probably we will have to test the code ourself....